# Accessing Parent View Controller from ContainerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

This should be something easy , but it's not working  as in both parentViewController and presentingViewController is returned nil;

I present the child view controller as a  container view ,

```
[self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
```

How can I  access the parent view controller from this container view ?

Comment: Question is not so clear ... plz elaborate more..!!

Comment: I don't think you need to call `didMoveToParentViewController` yourself. And I really don't think `self.parentViewController` is nil. Are you sure you're looking at the right view controller?

Comment: Can you share your views hierarchy?

Comment: This question was asked many times on SO.  In the child you got to have a variable linking to the parent. When the child is created, set his variable to the parent. This way you will be able to address the parent from the child.